# How to change which language will be loaded in Android for debug purposes?

Tags: android, debugging, multilingual

I want to test how my application looks like, and force it to load some specific language, but I don't want and don't need it in production code, so it can be some switch in eclipse or some code in onCreate.

EDIT: I don't want to manually change this, I want code what will let me to automate my tests.

Comment: Why don't you just set the language on the device/emulator?

Comment: I didn't want to mess with my device. :|

Comment: Huh? Nothing should happen if you switch languages :)

Comment: Ok, but how about automating things? I am too lazy to go to settings everytime. It will be beter with some code wrapped in 1 method call. :)

Answer (score 4):

I did something like this in my onCreate method:

```
// LOCALE
if (DEBUG == true)
{
    Misc.setLocale(this, "en"); // change "en" to "fr" for french
}
```

And here is `setLocale` method:

```
public static void setLocale(Context context, String language)
{
    final Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    final Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Now I can really fast change languages, I don't need to bother with emulator or settings in my device. I also can't forget about this, because of checking for DEBUG value.

Comment: Update for Android 17+: config.locale is deprecated. Instead use config.setLocale(locale);. The locale should be changed prior to setContentView() in onCreate() - otherwise it won't have an effect..

Answer (score 0):

Just change the language on your emulator. If you need to run automated tests against particular languages, just define separate AVDs configured for each language.

Any code you call is just going to force the same thing to happen as if you had changed the settings.